# How to pass exceptions to the first instance?

Tags: python, exception

How can I pass any occuring exception to the first instance which is responsible for all function calls (in this example function3())?
Is there a simple solution?

**Edit**:
The problem is that function3() is in module1 and function2() and function1() in module2. function1() calls a Tkinter-based function which throws the exception: Exception in Tkinter callback (...) IndexError which is not being handled in the except-block

```py
def function1():
   #Call another function which throws an exception

def function2():
   function1()

def function3():
   try:
      function2()
   except:
      #Do xyz for any occuring exception during the execution
```

Comment: Your code looks good to me. If `function1` calls another function raising an exception, it will be catched in the `xyz` line.

Comment: I don't understand what's the Problem ? if an exception happens in function1 then it will be catched in function3 isnt that what you already want ?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The problem is that function3() is in module1 and function2() and function1() in module2. function1() calls a Tkinter-based function which throws the exception: Exception in Tkinter callback (...) IndexError which is not being handled in the except-block

Comment: An Exception is an object, you can return it to the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

```
def function1():
   raise Exception("Exc found!")

def function2():
   function1()

def function3():
   try:
      function2()
   except:
      import traceback
      traceback.print_exc()
```

Method `traceback.print_exc()` will catch the exception thrown at `function1` and print the traceback for it, but won't stop the software.
If you want just the message, you can do this:

```
def function1():
   raise Exception("Exc found!")

def function2():
   function1()

def function3():
   try:
      function2()
   except ValueError:
      print("Found a ValueError")
   except Exception as e:
      print(f"Exception found: {e}")
```

In this second case, if the exception thrown is a ValueError, it will print "Found a ValueError". If it's any exception that is instance of **Exception class** and not a ValueError, it will print "Exception found: [a message here]".

Note that there are some exceptions that aren't child of Exception class, but all exceptions are child of BaseException class.

Another note is that isn't a good practice to catch "All exceptions" with the same way. Treat them specifically, as this avoid bugs by catching wrong exceptions.

For more info, you can read the documentation about exceptions (FROM PYTHON DOCS):

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html